# OpenALPR on iOS can't build project Undefined symbols

Tags: ios, xcode, configuration, compiler-errors, objective-c++

I followed the instruction on the https://github.com/twelve17/openalpr-ios and was able to get the framework to compile. 
I created a file to test this out this below is my code.

```
#import "ImageConverter.h"
#import <opencv2/highgui/ios.h>
#import <openalpr/alpr.h>


@implementation ImageConverter
-(NSString *)stringFromPlate:(UIImage *)image{
    cv::Mat matImage;
    UIImageToMat(image, matImage);
    alpr::Alpr *myAlpr = new alpr::Alpr("US");
    myAlpr->isLoaded();
    myAlpr->setDetectRegion(true);
    myAlpr->setTopN(1); //fixé le nombre de plaque a trouver. si plus de 1 ca retourne plusieur resultat candida pour l'image.
    alpr::AlprResults myResult = myAlpr->recognize(matImage);

    return @(myAlpr->toJson(myResult).c_str()); //conversion a NSString

}
@end
```

When I build this I get the following errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "alpr::Alpr::Alpr(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      -[ImageConverter stringFromPlate:] in ImageConverter.o
  "alpr::Alpr::isLoaded()", referenced from:
      -[ImageConverter stringFromPlate:] in ImageConverter.o
  "alpr::Alpr::toJson(alpr::AlprResults)", referenced from:
      -[ImageConverter stringFromPlate:] in ImageConverter.o
  "alpr::Alpr::setDetectRegion(bool)", referenced from:
      -[ImageConverter stringFromPlate:] in ImageConverter.o
  "alpr::Alpr::setTopN(int)", referenced from:
      -[ImageConverter stringFromPlate:] in ImageConverter.o
  "alpr::Alpr::recognize(std::__1::vector<char, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      -[ImageConverter stringFromPlate:] in ImageConverter.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I read many problems related to get Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: or arm64.

I check my lib for the architecture and I got this check ok

/libopenalpr-xcode.a are: armv7 arm64

At this point I am a bit lost to why this is happenig, this is my first time integratin c++ code and using .mm files in iOS projects or in xcode at all.

Edit: This is a lib I am trying to get working, I got the Alpr lib from https://docs.google.com/document/d/1x8M1b-v-VnqwgfUx5NZWEaKEpGZ0bdiTQAa1TD9q7pQ/edit

I was able to compile the framework with out errors but this said some setting are wrong in this projet and is preventing me from using this.

Edit: 2018/07/13 - I am no longer working for the company I was at the time I had created this Question. I ended up not having the time to test this more and the test project I initially created is now deleted since then.

Comment: I'm the author of the project to compile openalpr on iOS. I've revamped the process so it is scripted now. Can you give it a shot with the updated code? The readme has updated instructions, and now there's also a sample app you can try.

Comment: ok, I will when I have a bit of time.

Comment: @twelve17 Can you guide us on how to compile the latest OpenAlpr for iOS? Thanks.

Comment: @ZhouHao I have not worked on that project for some years, so I am no longer familiar with it. Sorry.